# Formula to find a cell data among a column and then copy the detail associated with it in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hope that you are feeling great today : )

I am looking to a formula with which I would be able to find a match for a cell among a column of data and then copy the associated detail next to it.

Let me give you a simple example below:

[image]

So the main problem is that I cannot use simply a VLOOKUP because I am not trying to compare the "(match)Column" cells with the "(search)Column" and "(data)Column" - but quite the opposite way around.

I have tried to use the following formula but unfortunately without any success:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(”*” & A1 & ”*”,$B$1:$B$3,0)),"-","A1")
```

in which - reflecting to the sample: A1 is the first cell of (search)Column and B1:B3 is the (data)Column.

Thank you very much in advance for your kind help and I wish you a further nice day!

Comment: Sorry - somehow it has ruined the example.. : / What I wanted to show is this: https://imgur.com/VqkUrJT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

The formula in `D2` translates to:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$A$2:$A$4&" ",C2))*ROW($A$2:$A$4)))
```

Comment: Sorry - somehow it has ruined the example.. : / What I wanted to show is this: https://imgur.com/VqkUrJT